# How to have different webapp resources for container:start and package tasks in SBT

Tags: sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I have a web application with pure JS frontend and Scala backend. I would like to use Grunt in my build pipeline to process **src/main/webapp** into target **dist/webapp** dir with concatenated/minified js and html files, compiled sass sheets etc. I also want to preserve original JS and HTML files for local testing using container:start task, while the package task would build my WAR file with resources processed by Grunt.
When I use following setting in SBT:

> webappResources in Compile <<= baseDirectory { bd => Seq(bd / "dist" / "webapp") }

then I achieve the second goal - my WAR gets built using the webapp resources in **dist/webapp**. However, when using container:start during local development I get bound to the same directory.
Is there any way to define different dirs for different purposes?

Comment: How does the build configuration look like? Could you prepare a sample application to play with and publish it on github? I doubt I've got enough knowledge to develop one myself.

Answer (score 1):

[xsbt-web-plugin supports SBT 0.13.1](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/project/build.properties) so you can use the much-nicer syntax to define `webappResources` in the `Compile` scope:

```
webappResources in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "dist" / "webapp")
```

I might be mistaken, but `webappResources` alone would work, too.

```
webappResources := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "dist" / "webapp")
```

or even (unless you want to replace the original value not to append a value):

```
webappResources += baseDirectory.value / "dist" / "webapp"
```

As for the solution I'd use the following (**untested**) in `build.sbt`:

```
webappResources in package := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "dist" / "webapp")
```

and leave the default value for the `webappResources` setting for local development.

Read [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) to learn more about "scoping" settings, i.e. setting different values for different *axes*.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of simplified syntax of SBT 0.13 but switching from 0.12 is a different task, requiring some additional work which I left for later.
I have tried using different values than `Compile` (``package``, `packageWar`, `packageBin`) but unfortunately it didn't do the job (I still get unprocessed resources in the WAR file).