# webappResources in package := Seq(baseDirectory.value ....) throws Error parsing expression

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I try to configure sbt (version 0.9.0) to use webapp/dist as the webappResource directory when running package task in sbt, and webapp/app as the webappResource directory when running the container:start command, following this description:

[How to have different webapp resources for container:start and package tasks in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996993/how-to-have-different-webapp-resources-for-containerstart-and-package-tasks-in)

But it throws the following error:

```
    error: eof expected but 'package' found.
    webappResources in package := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "webapp" / "dist") 
                       ^
    [error] Error parsing expression.
```

I guess that package is a reserved word also in sbt conf file, any other way to override setting in package task?

The reason for doing this is that I use gulp to manage webclient. Gulp runs the project from app folder, and compiles (minification etc.) the webclient project into dist folder. When I develop, I use the webapp/app folder as declared below:

```
    webappResources in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "webapp" / "app")
```

When I create a release, I first build (minification etc.) the webapp client into webapp/dist using gulp. Then I want to package webapp/dist content into the final war.

But I am not able to override the setting above to use webapp/dist, when using the package task.

I have also tried to create my own configuration like this:

```
    webappResources in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "webapp" / "app")

    lazy val ReleaseWarConfig = config("release-war") extend (Compile)

    val root = (project in file(".")).
      configs(ReleaseWarConfig).
      settings(inConfig(ReleaseWarConfig)(webSettings): _*).
      settings(
        webappResources in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value/"src"/"main"/"webapp"/"dist")
    )
    // I have also tried webappResources in ReleaseConfig instead of Compile ..
```

But it still uses the webapp/app directory instead of webapp/dist directory.

Any help would be very much appreciated !!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is the directory layout of your project?  It sounds like you have your Web application resources directory at *[myproject]/webapp/dist/*, meaning you have *WEB-INF/* and *WEB-INF/web.xml* (and various other optional resources) under *[myproject]/webapp/dist/* as well.  Is this correct?

To set the location of your Web application resources directory to *[myproject]/webapp/dist/*, add the following setting to your sbt configuration:

*build.sbt*:

```
webappSrc in webapp <<= (baseDirectory in Compile) map  { _ / "webapp" / "dist" }
```

You can read more about this setting [in the readme](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#change-the-default-web-application-resources-directory).

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned I use 0.9.0. I do exactly as you suggest, but with the base directory webapp/app for "develop mode". When creating a release, I use gulp to compile webclient (minification etc.) into resulting folder webapp/dist. I want to use webapp/dist as webappSrc when issueing the package command. So here is the problem, I am not able to override the webapp/app setting for package command. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: Oh, sorry - I misunderstood your question.  I think with 1.0.0 I would use [postProcess](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#modify-the-contents-of-the-prepared-web-application) to handle this, but I'm not sure about 0.9.0.  I'll see if I can figure this out for 0.9.0 later tonight.